# Bootstrap will not load from index.html file or aboutme.file, receiving error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, http-status-code-404, linker-errors

The site will load in plain html (MikeArce93@github.io) but will not load the any of the css or js files. `

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<!-- Google fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,600%7CFira+Sans:300,400,400i,600" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Material icons -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme.css">

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" href="assets/img/icon.png" type="image/png">

<!-- JS -->
<script src="assets/js/theme.js" defer></script>`
```

Files are titled theme.css and seem to be in the correct folders.[image: File List]

Answer (score 0):

So you're loading the index.html. We are working with that directory.

The './' means current directory.

Also, it looks like your JS folder is in you CSS folder. They should be separated.

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/theme.css">

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" href="./assets/img/icon.png" type="image/png">

<!-- JS -->
<script src="./assets/css/js/theme.js" defer></script>`
```